# Keyboards writes "bad" space characters in gnome terminal

Tags: command-line, keyboard, gnome-terminal

It looks like at random times my keyboard inserts a character that is displayed as a space character but isn't one, preventing the shell from interpreting it correctly. **For example before "sort" below :**

```
yannick@yannick-ubuntu:~/Pictures/Photos$ ls | grep "2015" | sort
No command ' sort' found, did you mean:
 Command 'psort' from package 'radiance' (universe)
 Command 'sort' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'tsort' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'msort' from package 'msort' (universe)
 sort: command not found
```

If I go back in history, delete the "bad" space and write another one, then the command works fine :

```
yannick@yannick-ubuntu:~/Pictures/Photos$ ls | grep "2015" | sort
20150101
20150103
20150107
20150109
20150111
20150115
```

Any ideas what happens ?

I enter all my commands using keyboard (no copy / paste), I am using gnome terminal on ubuntu 14.04, and I have a french (azerty) keyboard.

Comment: Are you using the AltGr key to enter the pipe? I *think* you might have to press space twice. Once to end the symbol input and then once for the regular space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I figured it out ! When I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, a non-breaking space is inserted, which *looks exactly like a space*... but isn't one.

On a french keyboard, the pipe character is inserted using <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>.
What happens is sometimes the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is still down when I press the <kbd>Space</kbd>, which is why this "bad" space character is inserted.

This problem has a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/218637) on launchpad. The suggested solution is to use the following command so that no non-breaking spaces are inserted :

```
setxkbmap -option "nbsp:none"
```

To do it permanently, I added the line in `.bashrc` and it works fine ! Note that doing it in `.profile` doesn't work (I guess if it's not in `.bashrc` the shell overrides it at startup)

Comment: Yes I'll have to wait for two days : http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/